# Renew command for \parencite if db entry type is @online

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I need to change the command `\parencite` for a specific case but I have absolutely no clue how to rewrite ist. Could anyone help me?

What I have as a database entry is this:

```
@online{ref1,
   author = {{A Company}},
   title = "Page Title",
   year = "no date",
   url = {https://url.xy},
   urldate = "2017-10-14"
}
```

If I now use `\parencite`, I will get

> Some text (A Company, no date).

But what I need is

> Some text (A Company, online).

So basically, I need to overwrite \parencite for the following criteria:

- IF the db entry is @online AND IF there is "no date" specified in
  'year', PRINT (author, online).
- IF there are several entries of the same author and declared with @online without a date, PRINT (author (a), online).
- In every other case, use the APA-Citation style as before
- No impacts on bibliography!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\NewBibliographyString{from}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   retrieved = {Abgerufen am},
   from = {von},
   nodate = {{}},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\sample.bib}
    @online{ref1,
       author = {{A Company}},
       title = "Title",
       year = "no date",
       url = {https://url.xy},
       urldate = "2017-11-15"
    }

    @online{ref2,
       author = {{A Company}},
       title = "Page Title",
       year = "no date",
       url = {https://url.xy},
       urldate = "2017-10-14"
    }
 \end{filecontents}
 \begin{document}
 There is some text \parencite{ref1} and some other \parencite{ref2}.
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You say 'no changes on the bibliography', but with your current set up you get 'no date' in an otherwise German bibliography. Is that not a bit weird? If you write in post-1996 orthography, you need `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (`ngerman` with **`n`**  instead of `german`). With recent versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` is not needed any more and it does nothing in your example since the document uses `german` and not `ngerman`. The same holds for `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}`.

Comment: I actually write 'ohne Datum' instead of 'no date'... so you mean I just use 'german' everywhere?

Comment: The document as shown uses only `german`. None of the settings for `ngerman` are picked up and you will get possibly incorrect (read: old orthography) hyphenation and string translations.

Comment: ah I see, thanks. Is there also a way for German in Switzerland?

Comment: `nswissgerman` for new orthography and `swissgerman` for old.

Answer (score 1):

*Obligatory warning*: Any changes to `biblatex-apa` will result in a style that is not APA-compliant any more. Proceed with care and only if you must.

I am working under the assumption that your text is written in `nswissgerman` as discussed in the comments.

The macro `cite:plabelyear+extradate` prints the year in citations. The macro is modified to not print `nodate` but to skip the year and print the entry type (online in this case) instead.

There is no need to write `year = {no date}` or similar if there is no date. Just don't give a `year` at all if there is none. `biblatex` can figure the rest out on its own.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nswissgerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\NewBibliographyString{from}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{nswissgerman}{
  retrieved = {Abgerufen am},
  from      = {von},
  nodate    = {{}ohne Datum},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate:special}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelyear}{nodate}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield[extradate:special]{extradate}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{entrytype}}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
           \clearfield{labelmonth}% don't want months in citations
           \clearfield{labelday}% don't want days in citations
           \clearfield{labelendmonth}% don't want months in citations
           \clearfield{labelendday}% don't want days in citations
           \iffieldsequal{labelyear}{labelendyear}% Don't want no-op year ranges
             {\clearfield{labelendyear}}
             {}%
           \iffieldundef{origyear}{}
             {\ifboolexpr{ test {\iforigdatecirca} or test {\iforigdateuncertain} }
               {\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}
               {\printorigdate}%
              \setunit*{\addslash}}%
          \ifboolexpr{ test {\iflabeldatecirca} or test {\iflabeldateuncertain} }
            {\mkbibbrackets{\printlabeldateextra}}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}%
        \iffieldundef{issue}
          {}
          {\addcomma\addspace\printfield{issue}}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ref1,
  author = {{A Company}},
  title = "Title",
  url = {https://url.xy},
  urldate = "2017-11-15"
}

@online{ref2,
  author = {{A Company}},
  title = "Page Title",
  url = {https://url.xy},
  urldate = "2017-10-14"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
There is some text \parencite{ref1} and some other \parencite{ref2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tina If the answer helped you, you may want to consider upvoting and accepting it, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers